# $S=\left \{z\in\mathbb{C}| (z+i)^{n}=(z-i)^{n} \right \}$ $S=?$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

If $n\in\mathbb{N}, n\geq2$ and $S=\big \{z\in\mathbb{C}| (z+i)^{n}=(z-i)^{n} \big \}$ then $S=?$ The right answer is 
$$
S=\left \{\operatorname{ctg}\frac{k\pi}{n} |1\leq k\leq n-1;k\in\mathbb{N}\right \}
$$

I started like this $\left(\frac{z+i}{z-i}\right)^{n}=1$. How to continue? Some ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Let be $\omega_k$, $k = 1,\dots,n$ the $n-$th roots of 1. Then, solve each equation
$$\frac{z+i}{z-i} = \omega_k.$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $z \in S$ implies that $|z+i|=|z-i|$.

Furthermore we have $|z+i|=|z-i| \iff z \in \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{z+i}{z-i} = \frac{x + (y+1)i}{x + (y-1)i} = \frac{x^2 -  y^2 + 1}{x^2 + (y-1)^2} + \frac{2xy}{x^2 + (y-1)^2}i = r e^{i\theta}$$
so
$$r = \vert \frac{z+i}{z-i} \vert = \sqrt{ \frac{(x^2 -  y^2 + 1)^2}{(x^2 + (y-1)^2)^2} + \frac{4x^2y^2}{(x^2 + (y-1)^2)^2} } = 1$$
which is
$$  (x^2 -  y^2 + 1)^2+4x^2y^2   = (x^2 + (y-1)^2)^2 \tag{1}$$
Another equation could be obtained from the phase, that is 
$$n\theta = 2k\pi \tag{2}$$
where $\theta = \arctan \frac{2xy}{x^2-y^2 + 1} $

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

You have $\;\dfrac{z-i}{z+i}=\mathrm e^{\tfrac{2ik\pi}n},\enspace k=0,1\dots n-1$.

Solve for $z$, remembering that $\cos x$ and $\sin x$ can also be written as
$$\cos x=\frac{\mathrm e^{2ikx}+1}{2\,\mathrm e^{ikx}},\qquad\sin x=\frac{\mathrm e^{2ikx}-1}{2i\,\mathrm e^{ikx}}.$$

Comment: I didn't learn at school the solution with $e^{...}$ I got  $\frac{z-i}{z+i}=\cos(\frac{2k\pi}{n})+i\sin(\frac{2k\pi}{n})$

Comment: That's the same thing. Note both are compatible with De Moivre's formula.